# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras' has no attribute 'abs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am working on an image classification problem with multiple classes and I follow the siamese face recognition sample [here](https://medium.com/predict/face-recognition-from-scratch-using-siamese-networks-and-tensorflow-df03e32f8cd0).  I have saved processed data in .npy format and I have used `Lambda` in the siamese model.  It shows an error in `<lambda>` :

```
distance_euclid = Lambda( lambda tensors : K.abs( tensors[0] - tensors[1] ))( [output_x1 , output_x2] )
```

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras' has no attribute
> 'abs'

---

Here are the package versions I'm using:

```
keras        2.3.1
python       3.6.10
tensorflow   2.1.0
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't modify the script inbetween? It says `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K`, yet you are seeing an error about `tensorflow.python.keras`

Comment: When i use 'import tensorflow.keras.backend as K' it gives an 'attributeError: module 'tensorflow has no attribute 'python''. So i have changed it to 'tf.python.keras'. @NilsWerner

Answer (score 0):

`abs` should be imported from `tf.keras.backend` (`tf.keras.backend.abs`) seems you are importing `tf.python.keras`. In your `import` modify this `tf.python.keras` line to `tf.keras.backend`

In addition, don't forget to upgrade `tensorflow`:

```
pip install -U tensorflow
```

Comment: Yes when i used 'tf.keras.backend' it gives an 'AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python''.

Comment: which version of tensorflow  are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow   2.1.0 as i mentioned above. @tasnuva